# Get quantity of MySQL GROUPs

Tags: mysql

What would be the best way to return the quantity of groups? Nothing special about my schema; table2 includes a FK referencing table1.  The following seems to work.  Any problems with it? Any better ways?  Thanks

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM table1 AS t1
 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
 WHERE t1.x=1 AND t2.y=1
 GROUP BY t2.z
) AS grouping
```

Comment: Do you want to know, in effect, how many rows are returned by the subquery?

Comment: @Strawberry.  I don't really care how many rows are returned by each subquery.  I only used the second COUNT(*) since the queries are PHP generated, and it made it easier than remembering which column to include in the SELECT...  Hey, why not just SELECT 1 instead of SELECT COUNT(*)?  Thanks for making me think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your solution is fine.

Another way would be

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.z) 
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
WHERE t1.x=1 AND t2.y=1
```

This will also include NULLs.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-null.html):

> Aggregate (summary) functions such as COUNT(), MIN(), and SUM() ignore NULL values. The exception to this is COUNT(*), which counts rows and not individual column values.

Comment: I like your solution more than mine (provided it works!).  I am sure it will work, but will test it first.  Thanks!

Comment: What about if `t2.z` column can have `NULL` values?